# How Can I use for-loop to solve this task?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a txt file which contains only integers. Each line contains 1 integer.
The txt file is representing  pits and their depth in the ground:
[image]

For example:
0
0
0
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
2
2
1
0

In this case, the pit starts from the index 3 and ends at index 13.
Lets say the user input is 10. The depth of the pit is 2m at index 10.
From the 10. index I need to go backwards until I reach the index with value of 0 to determinate the beginig of the pit. After I need to go forward until I reach 0 again to determinate the end of the pit.
How would you go about this?

```
int in = sc.nextInt();
int input = Integer.parseInt(data.get(in - 1));
if (input == 0) {
    System.out.println("There is no pit at this index!");
}

for (int i = input; i < data.size(); i--) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(data.get(i)) == 0) {
        System.out.println("The first index of the pit : " + data.get(i + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = input; i < data.size(); i --) {` Since you are going backwards, the condition should be `i >= 0`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be using `in` there, which is the user's inputted index?

Comment: Your image, data, and explanation don't seem to match.

Comment: @WJS Image is an example for understanding the task. The txt file contains 1 integer/line however the picture helps you understand the logic.

Comment: _"I need to go backwards [...] After I need to go forward"_ Sounds like two separate for-loops then. Both would start from the given index. Going through all the data (forwards only) just once and remembering the last index of zero depth is one way, but it's horribly inefficient if there's a lot of data, so I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Yes I was trying to solve this by 2 for-loops. Can you suggest a different way please?

Comment: @user16320675 My mistake.. sorry. My example was "0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 1 0" for the pit. So the pit starts at index 3 and ends at index 13.

Comment: @N.K Thank you very much for expressing your thoughts on my learning journey. I strongly agree with most of your statements, however what you presume is not my case. 
I will be studying programming next year and the task I brought to you is a small part of the final exams for entry level programming. At the moment I am doing this for getting introduced with Java. I am interested in Java language and wanted to try to solve this task.  It is not asked by any professor or anyone else.

Comment: @N.K I am doing this because I am interested in this field. All exams are available online in my country so I am welcomed to try. Please consider that there are people who are doing this as a hobby or trying to get some experience before going to universities. If you believe the question asked is too easy to solve or the OP is lazy, feel free to express your opinion but make sure you don't force your preconception about someone asking for help on StackOverflow.

Comment: My assumption was wrong, that's my bad, however i stand by what i say. If you're looking to learn then you should start by learning the langage itself, what can it do, through options like open classrooms for example, and then ask questions related to specific concepts, not directly ask for the whole reflexion to be fed down your throat. No matter the context (ie: student, amateur, whatever else) this is not an effective way to learn. I can guarantee you next time you'll encounter a similar problem you won't be able to reproduce that chain of thoughts by yourself, not as accurately.

Comment: In any case, i sincerely wish you the best in your learning journey, good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upon thinking about this some, I came up with an improved solution which does not require storage of the values nor does it require multiple loops.
This presumes that the first element in the file is the starting position (`threshold`) and what follows are the depths. It is up to you to make adjustments to suit your situation.

- The basic idea is to read in the values until the threshold is reached, only changing `start` if a depth of `0` occurs.
- Once the threshold is met, simply continue reading until a depth of `0` is found or until the end of file is reached, incrementing `end` as appropriate

```
String fileName = "<your filename>";
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
    int threshold = in.nextInt();
    int index = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int start = 0;
    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
       int depth = in.nextInt();
       if (depth == 0 && index < threshold) {
           start = index+1;
       }
       if (index >= threshold && depth == 0) {
          break;
       }
       end = index;
       index++;
    }
    if (end < threshold) {
        System.out.printf("No pit at index %d%n", threshold);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Pit starts at index %d and ends at index %d%n",
                start, end);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
    fne.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate your time for my problem. Fortunately The file is not so large  so its a perfect solution.

Comment: @Nicoden I came up with an improved solution.